# sending/receiving the value as a message or writing/reading the value from a file

Tags: return-value

I have several hosts in mininet and a controller responsible for monitoring these hosts. Hosts are supposed to do some processing and produce an integer value (which is updated periodically) and the controller is responsible for checking the values produced by these hosts (so controller should somehow get the value produced by each host)

To do so, I was thinking about **sending a UDP packet from each host to the controller periodically** containing the updated produced value

or

**creating separate text files for each host to write this value** which is updated each second, so that controller will read the content of these files periodically for getting the updated value.

But since I'm new in programming, I wanted to know which one will be a more reasonable solution (considering overhead, complexity and any other similar factor)